# Google event's occurrences time generation DST rules

Tags: google-api, calendar, dst, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to implement occurrence generation locally, not to call Google API every time I need them, however, I'm confused by the date time that Google generates for the occurrences in case of DST.

For example, let's consider my TimeZone:
https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/timezone/europe--kiev

We had standard time starting at 29 Oct 2017 3:00 AM and we will have DST at 25 March 2018 3:00 AM.

If I create a recurrent event for every day starting at 3:00 AM, I have the following start/end combinations from Google:

```
 - 28 October 2017: 00:00:00-01:00:00 
 - 29 October 2017: 01:00:00-02:00:00 
 - 30 October 2017: 01:00:00-02:00:00
 - 24 March 2018:   01:00:00-02:00:00 
 - 25 March 2018:   01:00:00-02:00:00 
 - 26 March 2018:   00:00:00-01:00:00
```

If I create a recurrent event for every day starting at 6:00AM, I have the following start/end combinations from Google:

```
 - 28 October 2017: 03:00:00-04:00:00 
 - 29 October 2017: 04:00:00-05:00:00 
 - 30 October 2017: 04:00:00-05:00:00
 - 24 March 2018:   04:00:00-05:00:00 
 - 25 March 2018:   03:00:00-04:00:00 
 - 26 March 2018:   03:00:00-04:00:00
```

As you can see from the logs the time that is generated behaves different depending on whether event is before time switch or after. 
But is the general rule for calculating this time? e.g. why in first case 29 Oct and 30 Oct have same time, but 25 Mar and 26 Mar have different time?

Comment: I have a similar problem, but no solution.  Posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925210/handling-dst-in-google-api-using-java .